# How to implement custom sort in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The ids in my documents are alphanumeric (like A-1,A-2,A-10,A-21). When I sort the documents based on these ids then the results are like :

```
A-1 A-10 A-2 A-20
```

but I want them like

```
A-1 A-2 A-10 A-20
```

To achieve this, how can I write custom scripts for sorting in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Check this library:

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-naturalsort

In the example, there is this order:
[Bob: 2 points, Bob: 3 points, Bob: 10 points]